# Linking read more button to id of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my read more button to link to particular section of another page. for example, i have about.html where i have displayed the staff images, excerpt description and a read more button. Full description of each staff can be red from the bio.html where i have entered the complete description.

When some one clicks on the read more button of a particular staff it is suppose to go to the description section of that particular staff, not to the top of the bio.html page.

**HTML Code:**

```
<li>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img_block wrapped_img">
            <img src="img/pictures/team1.jpg" alt="Tom" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel_title">
            <h6>Saul Yarmak</h6>
            <div class="op">Chairman & CEO</div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel_desc">
            <div class="exc">Saul Yarmak has the distinguished honor or repeating his role as Chairman of BXI.</div>
            <div class="read_more">
                <a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html" #bio6>Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a syntax-error. Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html#bio6"> Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you need to prevent default click event of your anchor here, try to use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$('.read_more a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

as well as changing your anchor link from:

```
<a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html"#bio6> Read More</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html#bio6"> Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, fix:

```
<a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html#bio6"> Read More</a>
```

And add on your `bio.html` `<a name="bio6"></a>` at the beginning of the needed description section.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Give  `<a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html#bio6"> Read More</a>`

Example:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-jQuery-object
it will show that id page

```
 <li>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="img_block wrapped_img"><img src="img/pictures/team1.jpg" alt="Tom" /></div>
              <div class="carousel_title">
               <h6>Saul Yarmak</h6>
               <div class="op">Chairman & CEO</div>
               </div>
               <div class="carousel_desc">                                                
               <div class="exc">Saul Yarmak has the distinguished honor or repeating his role as Chairman of BXI.</div>
                <div class="read_more">
                 <a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html#bio6"> Read More</a>
                  </div>
                  </div>
         </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html"#bio6>
```

will always lead you to page beginning

write it like

```
<a href="http://www.bxitrade.net/bio.html#bio6">
```

where bio6 is Id and name of the div or element you are pointing.